# SSH connection time out?

Tags: networking, ssh, iptables

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm trying to access via ssh from any computer. I've already altered the iptable configurations to accept all traffic from any IP, but I still got "the connection timed out" when trying to access it.

```
$ sudo iptables --list
Chain INPUT policy(ACCEPT)
target          prot  opt  source         destination
ACCEPT          tcp   ---  0.0.0.0/0      0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
```

Comment: Please, try to connect via ssh in verbose mode `ssh -v your_server` and show output.

Comment: it was successfull to me, but when I try to access form another computer the same error is shown, timedout.

Comment: Can you add more info to your question? Are you trying to access it from a computer in the same network? Have you installed openssh-server? Can you show the output requested by @metallic? What do you mean by 'it was successful to me'?

Answer (score 0):

Is the Ubuntu 16.04 box behind a firewall - like your ISP modem's firewall? If so you have to configure the modem firewall to have a NAT route for the ssh port (22) from the external network to your Ubuntu box.